# Error deploying Angular4 to ghpages using angular-cli-ghpages

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli, github-pages

I am trying to deploy a simple Angular 4 app to gh-pages. I have tried several methods and it seems that angular-cli-ghpages is the most up to date way to do it.

I've followed the instructions on the npm [angular-cli-ghpages page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages).

First I installed successfully angular-cli-ghpages,

```
$ sudo npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages
```

This command wouldn't work without sudo.

Next I created the dist folder and set the base-href,

```
$ ng build --prod --base-href "https://shanegibney.github.io/mathapp/"
```

Then I deployed with,

```
$ ngh
```

but this gives errors,

The output can be seen in this image below,

[image]

Running angular-cli-ghpages instead of ngh produces the same error,

[image]

I am using the following versions,

npm 3.10.10

angular-cli-ghpages ^0.5.1

node 6.9.4 (not really an issue here)

Thanks

Comment: what angular-cli version are you using? @ofey, check your package.json file :)

Comment: angular-cli-ghpages ^0.5.1 thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by added the following to the end of the scripts object in package.json,

```
"scripts": {

   "deploy": "ng build --prod --base-href 
   https://shanegibney.github.io/mathapp/ && angular-cli-ghpages --branch 
   gh-pages"
}
```

and then ran,

`$sudo npm run deploy`

So it seems that what was needed was the '--branch gh-pages' as an option, but there is nothing to suggest this on the npm page for angular-cli-ghpages.

Note if running these command separately without going through package.json I found it doesn't work,

`$ sudo ng build --prod --base-href https://shanegibney.github.io/mathapp/`

`$ sudo angular-cli-ghpages --branch gh-pages`

Got help from a [blog post](http://shermandigital.com/blog/deploy-an-angular-cli-application-to-github-pages/) on [shermandigital.com](http://shermandigital.com/blog/deploy-an-angular-cli-application-to-github-pages/)

Comment: not able to run angular-cli-ghpages --branch gh-pages

index.html could not be copied to 404.html. Continuing without an error.
An error occurred!
 Error: Unspecified error (run without silent option for detail)

Answer (score 7):

After git push origin master
gh - page deploy
step 1:"ng build --prod --base-href https://username.github.io/project-name/"

step 2: "ngh --dir dist/project-name"

replace project-name 
and username of with github username, project-name

Answer (score 5):

I deployed Angular2 app to gh-pages at last week([Live](https://arunasanjeewa.github.io/Angular2-CourseProject)).But I didn't use

**angular-cli-ghpages page.**

Used these dependencies -

- @angular/cli": "^1.2.0
- @angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1

Now need to build our project as minifiles css and js.
to do it just run this code in your angular project

```
ng build --prod--aot --base-href "https://username.github.io/repo-name/"
```

If you have problem when compiling
replace this code in angular-cli.json file

```
"environments": {
  "source": "environments/environment.ts",
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

to

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

After successful compiled(100%)
just run this command to deploy to gh-pahes

```
ngh --message "Deploy gh pages"
```

Comment: How did you not use `angular-cli-ghpages` page when you used `ngh` !?? ngh i suppose is short syntax for `angular-cli-ghpages`. https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages

Answer (score 4):

I ran the command as a superuser and it worked. Try it. If not, run the command with --no-silent to get more details. Example:

sudo angular-cli-ghpages --no-silent

Comment: Or sudo ngh --no-silent